# memory game how to flip current card with set attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm making a memory game and trying to flip a card to its image value. when I click on the card it should change the image to the current image in the array but for some reason, it's not working.

**JS**

```
var faces = []; //array to store card images
faces[0] = 'images/king-of-diamonds.png';
faces[1] = 'images/king-of-hearts.png';
faces[2] = 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png';
faces[3] = 'images/queen-of-hearts.png';

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function (cardId) {
    if (faces[cardId] === faces[cardId + 1]) {
        console.log("You found a match!");
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, try again.");
    }
}

var flipCard = function (cardId, name) {

    document.getElementById('image1')[this].getAttribute("id").src = faces[cardId]

    checkForMatch();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img onclick="flipCard(1,this)" id="image1" src="images/back.png" alt="Queen of Diamonds">
    <img onclick="flipCard(2,this)" id="image1" src="images/back.png" alt="Queen of Hearts">
    <img id="image3" src="images/back.png" alt="King of Diamonds">
    <img id="image4" src="images/back.png" alt="King of Hearts">
</div>
```

Comment: `id` attribute must be unique document-wise. You have `image1` used for two elements.

Comment: Thnx but how do i flip other cards when i click on them if i have diffedent ids? Do i make 4 different functions or something?

Comment: `this` will be set to the element that originated the event, you don't have to pass it. Simply use it in the `flipCard` function instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the same id in different elements. Id is thought to be unique and so you should not have more elements with the same id in the entire page.

At this point you can directly do:

```
var flipCard = function (cardId, name) {
    document.getElementById('image1').src = faces[cardId];
    checkForMatch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but how do i flip other cards when i clik on them? The solution above will only flip the 1st card but im trying to flip the card that was clicked

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can pass instead of the name in the function the id of the element and ensure to have different id for every element. var flipCard = function (cardId, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = faces[cardId];
    checkForMatch();
}. This will change the src of the passed img id with the carId passed.